# CRIT XMLTooling.Config : libcurl lacks > OpenSSL-specific options, this will greatly limit functionality error

Tags: curl, libcurl, shibboleth

I newly installed an upgrade of curl with openssl function. But I still get the Openssl specific option. Clearly shows I have open-ssl installed. Looks like shibboleth is picks the old curl to load from. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or [unix.se] or, if related to a production system problem, [sf] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Take this with a grain of salt. I'm a linux newb.

shibd -t is just a test for the config files. It doesn't know that the service is started with an environment parameter: Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/shibboleth/lib64 .
Check this with: `cat /lib/systemd/system/shibd.service`
Your service should have this parameter already so Shibboleth the service doesn't actually have this problem.
So shibd -t is in that sense faulty. It doesn't properly check your configuration.

To make shibd -t do what it is supposed to, you have to invoke it with:
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/shibboleth/lib64 /usr/sbin/shibd -t`

Found this at: https://services.renater.fr/federation/documentation/guides-installation/sp3/chap04

Comment: Answering my own answer here: This doesn't seem to happen on the anymore, so feel free to look for other potential answers to OP.